# Components missing in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js

I'm following a tutorial on EmberJS but seem to have an issue loading components. I created a component named gen-container, but upon adding GenContainer tag in a template, emberJS complains that the component can't be found.

I used the cli to generate the component.

YouTube tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HP7LoPx2Ivs&list=PLk51HrKSBQ88wDXgPF-QLMfPFlLwcjTlo&index=4

Index.hbs

```
<GenContainer>
  <LinkTo @route="item" @model="1">Product 1</LinkTo>
  <LinkTo @route="item" @model="2">Product 2</LinkTo>
</GenContainer>
```

gen-container.hbs

```
<LinkTo @route="cart" class="cart-link">
  <FaIcon @icon="shopping-cart" />
</LinkTo>

<main class="container mt-5">
  {{yield}}
</main>
```

Comment: Which ember version do you use? What error do you get?

Comment: where *exactly* is the `gen-container.hbs` file? is it `app/components/gen-container.hbs`? or `app/templates/components/gen-container.hbs`? Does the component also has a `gen-container.js` file? And what is your version of `ember-cli` and `ember-source` in `package.json`?

Comment: @AndreyStukalin I'm on version 3.9.0. 

Error: 
Uncaught Error: Attempted to resolve `gen-container`, which was expected to be a component, but nothing was found.

Comment: @Lux yes, it's app/components/gen-container.hbs I used the cli to generate the file. I'm using ember-cli version 3.9.0 and ember-source is ~3.26.1

Comment: so is there a `.js` file or not? why do you have this big difference between `ember-cli` and `ember-source`? could you maybe share your repo?

Comment: @Lux I don't see a .js file for components, the cli only seems to have made the .hbs file. Here's my repo. I'm not sure why the versioning is so different, I just installed with npm in my Mac environment.

https://github.com/yegamble/emberjs-tutorial

Comment: I think Ember CLI 3.9.0 does not support component template colocation yet and may just ignore a app/components/*.hbs file. I would recommend to upgrade ember-cli to a recent version.

Comment: can confirm, upgrading `ember-cli` to `^3.26.0` fixes the issue in the provided repo.

Comment: Okay thanks @Lux. I'll upgrade then.